# Whats wrong with this signal example?

Tags: c, signals

My instructor posted this program to give an example of signals, I tried to compile it but i got three warnings:

```
Buzzoff.c:17:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'alarm' is invalid in
  C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  alarm(2);
  ^
Buzzoff.c:21:5: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'exit' with type
  'void (int) __attribute__((noreturn))'
   exit(-1);
   ^
Buzzoff.c:21:5: note: please include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide
  a declaration for 'exit'
Buzzoff.c:33:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pause' is invalid in
  C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
pause();
^
3 warnings generated.
```

I still don't understand how signals work and cant seem to figure out whats exactly wrong with this program. could someone help me understand whats wrong and how to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void handler(int s)
{
  printf("Please wake up 1730 !!!!!!! \n");
}
int cnt = 0;

void boom(int s) 
{ 
  if (cnt<5) {
    printf("tick\n");
    cnt = cnt+1;
    alarm(2);
  }
  else {
    printf("Boom!\n");
    exit(-1);
 }  
}

int main()
{
   signal(SIGINT, handler);
   signal(SIGALRM, boom);  

   alarm(5);
   while(1) {
    printf("...ZZZZzzzzz...\n");
    pause();
 }

}
```

Comment: What are `SIGINT` and `SIGALARM`?

Comment: @haccks, they are signals defined by Linux (Posix actually)

Comment: They are warnings, not errors. Include <stdlib.h> to fix the exit warning .

Comment: @markon, did you look at the code?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I remember that stdio.h and stdlib.h were not included. I only saw signal.h and unistd.h.

Comment: @markon, haha, I see that happened to me two. You had the code scrolled down, so the top two lines didn't show

Answer (score 5):

Besides the fact that `signal` is deprecated and [`sigaction`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) is its replacement, there's nothing wrong with the code. The only problem is that there are some files that should have been included but they are not which is what the compiler is trying to tell you.

**However**, the code contains the correct header files! [`alarm`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm) and [`pause`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pause) are defined in `unistd.h` and [`exit`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit) is defined in `stdlib.h`, both of which are included. If your compiler is complaining about those files, there's something wrong with the compiler, or the installation of the standard libraries.

Possible problems could be a bad OS (read Windows), bad installation (by a crazy Linux distribution) or something you did wrong yourself, for example move some files you shouldn't have. Not understanding `alarm` and `pause` hints at a non-POSIX operating system such as Windows. However, not understanding `exit` hints at something very wrong with the compiler itself.

Can you also post the command you execute to compile the code? You don't happen to be including `-nostdinc` for some reason, do you?

Comment: Ahh I see I was compiling it on my mac. It might not have all the files it needs or in the right place. I went over to the school vm and compiled and it worked. Sorry my fault. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

on Mac and BSD simply give a strike to terminal:

NAME
alarm -- set signal timer alarm

LIBRARY
Standard C Library (libc, -lc)

SYNOPSIS
#include <unistd.h>

so You should simply include unistd.h, and You got it.

I tried on my BigSur on terminal:

ingconti@MBP-32GB-BigSur signal % ./stackoverflow

```
...ZZZZzzzzz...
tick
...ZZZZzzzzz...
tick
...ZZZZzzzzz...
tick
...ZZZZzzzzz...
tick
...ZZZZzzzzz...
tick
...ZZZZzzzzz...
Boom!
```

so it WORKS on Mac!